# Python-telegram-bot: How can I get customized number latest message by bot in telegram api?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot, telegram-api

I found some function to get messages in group. But It used via client.
In this case, I want to get message with **bot**.
Any idea from all of you ?

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to get chats with a bot account on Telegram.

As a workaround you can forward messages with id starting from 1 to the latest message id sent to the group, to your chat.

Or store the messages with id and chatId in a database and forward them to your private chat with the bot. If information about the sender is not important, you can as well store message texts and medias based on the message type.

Check forward message [here](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api/#forwardmessage).

```
bot.forward_message(chat_id='where_to_forward_chat_id',
                        from_chat_id='from_chat_id',
                        message_id='message_id')
```

Comment: so, I could get message via message_id because, 2 adjacent messages do not mean 2 adjacent message_id

Comment: message ids are specific to each group or channel or conversation. You can't have 2 same messageIds in a group. So you need to save chatId and messageId in a database to use later.